Using pip to install a github pull request (404 not found)
According to pip: how to install a git pull request I should be able to use pip to install a library with an unmerged pull request, eg.
python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py.git@refs/pull/294/merge

The merge at the end auto-merges the PR.
This used to work for me. However, recently when I've tried to redeploy my app, I now get an error saying that url is 404 not found (and in fact, it's true if I open the url in the browser).
Why would this url have worked in the past but now no longer be available? How might I work around the issue?

The pull request https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py/pull/294 was closed, i.e., rejected. As it's now closed its "merge" reference is no longer available. You can try to use "head" (works for me):
pip install git+https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py.git@refs/pull/294/head

Or install from the repo where the PR was originated:
pip install git+https://github.com/c0j0s/notion-py.git

